# is it possible that sharepoint column formatting call multiple actions?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am learning SharePoint column formatting custom action.

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/formatting-syntax-reference#customrowaction

now I want to both use 'setvalue' and 'execute flow' on one button click. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it doesn't appear to be possible to use multiple actions on one button at this time.

Comment: Does anyone know if this is still the case as at August 2023?  It seems to be quite a common requirement - i.e click a button in a column which immediately changes a column value and then runs a flow.  The reason this behaviour is required is because if we just create a button to run a flow which updates a column value, this can take a few minutes, and the end user gets confused if what they wanted to do has been done or not.  So by combining the functionality of `setValue` and `executeFlow`, that would remove this problem.